# How to add an additional RewriteCond to exclude a specific url?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an existing .htaccess file with the following rewritecond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^go\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://go.domain.com [R,L]
```

In essence, everything on this domain is forced to the `go` subdomain.

However, there is one url that I would like to leave as-is, and not rewrite:

```
www.domain.com/terms
```

How do I add in an additional RewriteCond to exclude this specific url?

Answer (score 5):

Add a condition to exclude this URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/terms$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think preceeding this with

`^(www\.domain\.com/terms)$ $1 [L]`

might help (rewrite the special url with itself and don't continue).

Comment: When you say preceding, do you mean create a new RewriteCond or a new RewriteRule?